# Lua error loading module 'libpng' (Torch, MacOSX)

Tags: macos, lua, osx-yosemite, libpng, torch

How do I make libpng load properly in Lua?  I am running Lua/Torch in iTorch Notebook in Mac OSX 10.10.3, where other basic functions in Lua work, such as plotting and calculations.

```
 brew install libpng
```

> Warning: libpng-1.6.17 already installed

If I run:

```
require 'nn';
require 'image';
itorch.image(image.lena())
```

> error loading module 'libpng' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libpng.so':
>       dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libpng.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libpng.so
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: libpng.so requires version 33.0.0 or later, but libpng15.15.dylib provides version 29.0.0
>   warning:  could not be loaded (is it installed?)
>   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/dok/inline.lua:736:  libpng package not found, please install libpng
>   stack traceback:
>       [C]: in function 'error'
>       /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/dok/inline.lua:736: in function 'error'
>       /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:142: in function 'saver'
>       /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:355: in function 'save'
>       /Users/MY/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/gfx.lua:25: in function 'f'
>       [string "local f = function() return itorch.image(iii)..."]:1: in main chunk
>       [C]: in function 'xpcall'
>       /Users/MY/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:177: in function 
>       /Users/MY/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/poller.lua:75: in function 'poll'
>       /Users/MY/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:307: in function 'poll'
>       /Users/MY/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:325: in function 'sleep_ex'
>       /Users/MY/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/lzmq/impl/loop.lua:370: in function 'start'
>       /Users/MY/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/itorch/main.lua:344: in main chunk
>       [C]: in function 'require'
>       [string "arg={'/Users/MY/.ipython/profile_default/secu..."]:1: in main chunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem (OSX 10.9.5). You probably have multiple versions of libpng installed, with the one called during install of luarocks having architecture i386 (x86_64 required).

To solve this:

1. Try installing image again, and reading the log:

   luarocks install image
2. Check the log to see if you get a message of type:

   ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks//libpng.framework/libpng, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Library/Frameworks//libpng.framework/libpng (2 slices)
3. If this is the case (assuming using brew) remove the libpng framework in /Library/Frameworks and do a

   brew install libpng --universal
4. Reinstall image and run.

This worked for me, I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the image package as well as forcing the linkage of libpng might fix it:

```
brew link libpng --force
luarocks install image
```

Comment: I did that, and there were no errors directly from those commands, but going back to itorch, the same error loading module libpng occurs.  I uninstalled and reinstall lua itself too and no difference.  I even downloaded manually libpng from: 
http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/libpng/ 
but there was no difference.  Do my paths need setting to different directories?